# Reference request for Prof. Wilhelm Blashke's DG book

Tags: reference-request

Please suggest how can one get a copy of the book mentioned here:

[TA Guess_on_W Blashke](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183485618)

Is there an English translation of Professor Blashke's book on Differential Geometry?

(Einführung in die Differential Geometrie, Springer Verlag, Berlin/Heidelburg/Göttingen,1950)

EDIT1:

How  German *"Böschungslinien"* translate into English?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The translation of Böschungslinie is "helix", referring to a curve with nowhere disappearing curvature such that its torsion is a constant multiple of its curvature.

See Lancret's Theorem: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Lancret

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LancretsTheorem.html

Also I checked Springer's website, and I am fairly certain there are no English translations of his work. However they are all very old and out-dated.

Additionally, although this is an ad hominem attack, so not very logical, but the guy was a Nazi.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenntnis_der_deutschen_Professoren_zu_Adolf_Hitler#Verweigerer

Comment: Schönen Dank! I saw in his book it being applied to flat epicycloid types.

Comment: .. that are referred to as spirals with or without an out of plane twist component